# Decrease pandas series value if it is higher than the mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, mean

I am trying to decrease by 2.5% the value of all records that are higher than the mean in my pandas series.

I would like to solve the problem using the update method

```
price_per_city = {
    "Bragança": 10.3,
    "Braga": 10.6,
    "Porto": 11.5,
    "Aveiro": 12.3,
    "Coimbra": 9.9,
    "Leiria": 9.3,
    "Lisboa": 12.1,
    "Beja": 10.9,
    "Évora": 11.4,
    "Faro": 9.1
}

prcSerie = pd.Series(price_per_city)
prcSerie.update(prcSerie, prcSerie[prcSerie >=prcSerie.mean()])
print(prcSerie)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html) for in place modification:

```
prcSerie.update(prcSerie.loc[prcSerie>=prcSerie.mean()].mul(0.975).round(2))
```

Output:

```
Bragança    10.30
Braga       10.60
Porto       11.21
Aveiro      11.99
Coimbra      9.90
Leiria       9.30
Lisboa      11.80
Beja        10.63
Évora       11.12
Faro         9.10
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `where`:

```
prcSerie = prcSerie.where(prcSerie.le(prcSerie.mean()), prcSerie.mul(0.975))

>>> prcSerie
Bragança    10.3000
Braga       10.6000
Porto       11.2125
Aveiro      11.9925
Coimbra      9.9000
Leiria       9.3000
Lisboa      11.7975
Beja        10.6275
Évora       11.1150
Faro         9.1000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: is there anyway to limit to two decimals?

Comment: does the method le means less than?

Comment: `le`= less than or equal to, `lt` = less than

Comment: why does it work with le instead of gt ? Since I want to modify the  values higher than the mean shouldn't I use gt?

Comment: If it's `le` keep the original values, otherwise the value multiplied by 0.975. Look at the documentation for `pd.Series.where` to see how it works.

Comment: is there anyway to do it using the update and filtering?

Comment: Using `where` is easiest. If you have certain constraints about what functions to use, next time mention that in your question so you get more relevant answers.